# Finding nearby from current location in a list of place id's

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

Assuming i have a list of place id's. Lots of place id's.
How would i determine the place id's in the list which is nearby my current location ?

Comment: please add your code

Answer (score 0):

you should compute distance of each place to your current place.if the distance is less than a threshold like 3 kilometer is near you.

```
distancePow2=(yourLatitude - placeLatitude)^2 +(yourLongitude- placeLongitude)^2
if(distancePow2< thresholdPow2 )  => place is near you!
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is the place ID, then you can call [`GeoDataApi.getPlaceById()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/GeoDataApi.html#getPlaceById(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String...)) to fetch Place details for each Id. The Place objects returned from this call contain the latitude and longitude of each place.

You can then use [`Location.distanceBetween()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) to calculate the distance between each place and your current location.